# timestamp in database

Tags: datetime

This is a very simple question.

Some dates and timestamps are generated in my database.

How is this mdate build up so I can see what date and time is stored?

1st `1259575339` 2nd `1261296844`

I couldn't find a converter for this.

I have read that it's the the amount of seconds since 01-01-1970, is this correct?

Comment: i have no doubt that those are timestamps which is actually seconds from the UNIX epoch. in PHP you can use gmdate() and date() functions to format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 *(see [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on wikipedia, for more info)*.

In PHP, you have the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert timestamps to dates as strings ; for example, this portion of code :

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1259575339) . '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1261296844) . '<br />';
```

Will get you, in a browser :

```
2009-11-30 11:02:19
2009-12-20 09:14:04
```

In MySQL *(if that's your DB engine)*, you can use the [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert those to dates :

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(1259575339);
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1259575339) |
+---------------------------+
| 2009-11-30 11:02:19       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0,07 sec)

mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(1261296844);
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1261296844) |
+---------------------------+
| 2009-12-20 09:14:04       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```